# WebSocket connection to 'wss://...' failed

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io, spring-websocket, stompjs

I am trying to establish websocket connection to the spring boot web server deployed in azure from anuglar application.

But connections are not getting success every-time.
It always fail for first time and then get connected after some point of time.

The same is working if we run it in localhost (local), so no issues with local. Issues comes while running on azure server.

Attached console logs of both scenario local and server

Not sure what needs to be done to fix this issue.

Azure

[image]

Local

[image]

Comment: Any updates on this one? Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Binaya nope, but recently i have tried a simple application with plain javascript (without angular) and spring boot I didn't face this issue in local, we will be deploy it very soon, I will let you know